How can I elegantly locate elements without an ID when the website uses frameworks like Tailwind CSS?
Many modern websites are increasingly using frameworks like Tailwind CSS,
which rely heavily on utility classes (e.g., text-center, flex) rather
than IDs for styling. This can make it challenging to locate specific elements
in the DOM, especially for userscripts.
Are there any elegant solutions or best practices for locating elements that
do not have an ID attribute?

I'd look into what kind of solutions are used for identifying elements in good durable E2E tests. I think it's fundamentally the same question, even if your levers are a bit more limited since you can't modify the site.
